# Have multiple threads pulling data from one single function call

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I am currently stuck on how to approach this problem.

I have an program that is multi threaded. Each program requires some kind of unique tokens before moving on and doing it things. The only way to get tokens is through user interaction. As of right now, I have each thread instances open up web driver. As you can imagine, it is very insufficient and annoying, especially when I have over 10 instances running. I have to go through each instances and input in tokens.

So I am trying to come up with a way for me to just have one driver instances open up and have other threaded instance pull data from that one instance. But I don't know how to get started it.

Another problem would be if I do manage to get multiple instances pulling data off one web driver, what would be the most efficient way for me to manage so that threads don't try to pull same tokens.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using multiple instances of interpreter or some kind of paralleling library? (`threading` or `multiprocessing`). Can't you just save token to file and read it by all the instances?  Can't you fork after you already got a token?

Comment: I am using parallel threading. And no I can't. Tokens have to be input in real time and it depend on each instancs(meaning same token cant be reuse). And sometime, it won't be a one time thing. I would have to keep inputting in tokens until script successfully go through.